# Redirect old domain to new website via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Have an old webisite (oldwebsite.com) and want to redirect all the domain requests to the new website (newwebsite.com) via htaccess (probably).

How would you go with it? Need like all old pages to redirect to the new website homepage as the structure and pages are entirely diffirent.

Comment: Do the old and new domains point to the same place? "all old pages to redirect to the new website _homepage_" - although redirecting many to one like that is detrimental to SEO if that is a concern.

Comment: @MrWhite there is zero seo done on the old website, i'd rather have old.domain/any_url redirect to the new domain homepage

Comment: And what about my first question... "Do the old and new domains point to the same place?" - This affects the type of directive that would be required. And if they point to the same place, do you have an existing `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I don't even have access to the old website/server. We built a new site and want to sent a ready .htaccess code to the former developer to add.
All links will be diffirent. but that isn't really an issue, we've made a really nice 404 page that will guide new visitors through.

Comment: Are you saying you don't have access to the old domain - only the former developer has access to this (and the old hosting etc.)?! Are you still paying for the old domain/hosting?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

In general I would recommend to implement such general rules in the http server's central configuration of the host "old.example.com". You can instead use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but that comes with a few small disadvantages.